# how to get the values passed into an ajax post

Tags: ajax, variables, post

Here is my codes,

```
function getMods(name){
    var init;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "init.php",
    data: { 'id': getID(), 'Name': name },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
        {
            return data;
        },
        async:false
    });
}
function init(){
    var gm = '<br/>';
    var gm1 = getMods('Name');
        $('#brand').append(gm1);
    var gm2 = getMods('Owner');
    var gm3 = getMods('Admin1');
    var gm4 = getMods('Admin2');
    var gm5 = getMods('Admin3');
    var gm6 = getMods('Admin4');
    $('#online3').append(gm2 + gm + gm3 + gm + gm4 + gm + gm5 + gm + gm6 + gm);
}
```

The getMods() returned "undefined". When i use this code:

```
alert(data);
```

The page alerted the correct values.

Here is the php file init.php:

```
<?php
include('dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['Name'])){
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$init = chatMods($name,$id,$username,$password);
echo $init;
}
?>
```

And I add the async in the getMods().

Comment: what is the  code in init.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the distinction between a return value of a function (`getMods()` in your case) and a callback function (`success`).

In your code, you call `getMods()` which in fact doesn't return any value, hence you get *undefined*.

The `success` callback happens only after a while, after your function had already returned.

One possible solution for you (though not the greatest because it locks your JS processing) is to use an Ajax call in a **synchronous** way. A call that only returns when an answer from the server has been received. Use `async: false` in your `$.ajax` call, capture your return value and then return it. See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2592780/290343

You should be aware, of course, that your Ajax calls might fail and you need to take that into account. Also, your code might run really slow because it does 6 remote calls to a server.